# MonthBegin current month with anchor dates included

Tags: pandas

In the following snippet the anchor point behaves differently than the rest of the dates as described in the this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics).

Is there a way to easily change the behavior so that it ignores anchor points to behave like the rest of the dates?

In:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2016', end = '1/31/2016')

index + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)
```

Out:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
                   '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01'],
                  dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Notice how the first date 2016-01-01 is different since it's an anchor point?  Can I modify the behavior so that it consistent in the application of the offset?

Comment: I can write a customer function.  I was just wondering if there was something already built in.  I have a scenario where I have a field with a bunch of random dates that I want to set each date to the first day of each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider `index`

```
index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2016', periods=10, freq='W')
index

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-03', '2016-01-10', '2016-01-17', '2016-01-24',
               '2016-01-31', '2016-02-07', '2016-02-14', '2016-02-21',
               '2016-02-28', '2016-03-06'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-SUN')
```

***method 1***
Don't pass `0`
It freaks these methods out.

```
index + pd.offsets.MonthBegin()

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01',
               '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
               '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

***method 2***
kind of manually

```
pd.to_datetime(index.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01',
               '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01',
               '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Method 2 will works for me.  Thanks!  When I pass in method 1 for some reason it gives me the next month.  I'm running pandas version 0.18.1.

Comment: Took me a bit to understand the problem.  Thx for bringing it up.  I'll keep in mind the version difference

Comment: It just occurred to me that you could also do "index + pd.offsets.MonthBegin() + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)"